# How to exclude a classes from being kept by proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I added the following line in my proguard config:

```
 -keep class com.mypackage.** {*;}
```

But now proguard doesn't remove my class `com.mypackage.BuildConfig.class` from the result. And I want it to be removed.

How can I exclude a given class from being kept?

Thanks

Comment: The `keep` option is used to ask proguard to keep some elements (packages, classes, methods, ...). If you don't want to keep that class, you should remove that statement or refine it if you want a more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following rule:

```
-keep class !com.mypackage.BuildConfig, com.mypackage.** { *; }
```

Comment: Can this be applied to `extends` or `implements` keywords?