# Exclude .java class to be compiled to .aar file

Tags: android, build, compilation, aar

I am building a Android library(.AAR) which is consist of multiple packages. Is there any way to exclude some classes from been compiled to the library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060827/how-to-exclude-a-classes-from-being-kept-by-proguard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found.

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/className.java'
            }
        }
    }
```